# Azure webjob is always "Running"

Tags: azure-webjobs

I just created an azure web job. I scheduled it to run every 1 minute:

```
0 */1 * * * *
```

This is the code

```
 var host = new JobHost();
 Console.WriteLine("Starting program...");
 var unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
 unityContainer.RegisterType<ProgramStarter, ProgramStarter>();
 unityContainer.RegisterType<IOutgoingEmailRepository, OutgoingEmailRepository>();
 unityContainer.RegisterType<IOutgoingEmailService, OutgoingEmailService>();
 unityContainer.RegisterType<IDapperHelper, DapperHelper>();

 //var game = unityContainer.Resolve<IOutgoingEmailRepository>();
 var program = unityContainer.Resolve<ProgramStarter>();
 program.Run().Wait();
 Console.WriteLine("All done....");

 host.RunAndBlock();
```

The problem is that the status never change to "success". Am I doing smth wrong? The followings are the app settings I use, should I change? I also noticed that it runs just the first time, I believe it is because it never ends

[image]

Comment: when you use `host.RunAndBlock()` it ensures that the job will never ends. Try removing this line.

Comment: Does it ever changed to failed (due to timeout)?

Comment: Hi,any updates now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check your webkjob logs on `KUDU`.

If you use the above job in a `RunAndBlock` scenario, then your job has to be continuous. That means, the process will run all the time.

Obviously, you're using `Trigger webjob` here, not `Continuous`. `RunAndBlock` method can not be used here.

> WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT - Time in seconds after which we'll abort a
>   running triggered job's process if it's in idle, has no cpu time or
>   output (Only for triggered jobs).

In addition,I notice that you set `WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT` to `100000`.It seems that the value is too large so that it makes your webjob never stops for a long time when it's in idle.

You could also change the grace period of a job by specifying it (in seconds) in the settings.job file where the name of the setting is `stopping_wait_time` like so:

```
{ "stopping_wait_time": 60 }
```

More details ,please refer to this [doc](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs#configuration-settings).

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Indeed, there is never a scenario where you should call `RunAndBlock` for a non-continuous WebJob. You probably don't need to use the WebJobs SDK at all in your scenario. Just do your work from Main, and be done. Don't use any Host.

Comment: I marked this as an answer because I think that is a way to go to fix the problem. Tho, I found that the issue was related to a line of code (inside of program .Run()) : Console.ReadLine (). A silly error. That is why the app never finished.